# Possible to highlight columns when clicking on a row based on value in a certain cell of that row?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my situation:

I would like to highlight various columns when I click on any cell in a row based on values in a certain cell of the same row.

Example:

I click on Row 2 --> C2 says "blue" --> Columns B, D, E, F automatically highlights in yellow

Is this possible?  (preferably without re-running a macro each time i click on a different row)

Thanks!

Comment: Where's connection between yellow and blue - or simply what's the criteria of coloring?

Comment: See `Worksheet_SelectionChange Event`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple VBA, actually. Good luck.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lngRow As Long, intCol

lngRow = Target.Row

If Cells(lngRow, 3) = "Blue" Then intCol = 6 Else: intCol = 0

Columns(2).Interior.ColorIndex = intCol
Columns(4).Interior.ColorIndex = intCol
Columns(5).Interior.ColorIndex = intCol
Columns(6).Interior.ColorIndex = intCol


End Sub
```